# Making request headers accessible as a property in base controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, httprequest

I'm making a base controller for an api I'm developing that sends their application-id with every REST request. I'd like to have ApplicationID accessible as private property for all controllers to access.

```
  public class BaseApiController : ApiController
{
    private string ApplicationId
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers("x-application-id").ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

this errors out like this:

```
Non-invocable member 'System.Web.HttpRequest.Headers' cannot be used like a method.
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: is headers a property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Request.Headers` is a property of type [NameValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which has an indexer which returns a `string`.  You can use it like so:

```
public class BaseApiController : ApiController
{
    private string ApplicationId
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["x-application-id"];
        }
    }
}
```

As the indexer already returns a `string`, there's also no need to call `.ToString()` on the result.